# Sum of arrival times of Chinese Restaurant Process (CRP)

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, bayesian-probability, random-permutations, queueing-theory

Suppose that a random sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is drawn from a continuous spectrum of colors, or species, following a Chinese Restaurant Process distribution with parameter $|\alpha|$ (or equivalently $X_1,\ldots,X_n \mid P \sim P$ where $P$ is a Dirichlet process $\operatorname{DP}(\alpha)$ with atomless measure $\alpha$, because the CRP is the unique urn process associated with the DP). Therefore we assume that $X_i$ takes values in some measurable space $(S, \mathcal{S})$; for simplicity take $S = \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ equal to the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Assume that we keep track of the unique species $X_j^*$. We may do so by noting the arrival time of the $j$ th new color. Thus define $T_1=1$ and
$$T_j=\min \left\{n: \sum_{i=1}^n D_i=j \: \: \text{for} \: \: D_i=1 \:\: \text{if} \: \: X_i \notin\left\{X_1, \ldots, X_{i-1}\right\}\right\}$$

and setting $X_j^*=X_{T_j}$. A sequence $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ will contain a random number of unique species, usually denoted by $K_n$.

My question is: are there know results to compute:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{K_n} T_j \right]$$

The same question is also posted on MathstackExchange: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851045/sum-of-arrival-times-of-chinese-restaurant-process-crp), but given its difficulty, I posted it also here.

PS: also upper bounds of the above quantity are of interest to me.

PS2: the probability of a "new draw" for the Dirichlet process, i.e. $X_i \notin\left\{X_1, \ldots, X_{i-1}\right\}$, is given by $\frac{|\alpha|}{|\alpha|+i}$. Moreover the distinct values in a random sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ sampled from a distribution generated from a $\mathrm{DP}(\alpha)$-prior with atomless base measure form an i.i.d. sequence from $\bar{\alpha}$.

Comment: Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851045/sum-of-arrival-times-of-chinese-restaurant-process-crp Generally you should try one of the two sites first, so no duplication of effort in answering occurs

Comment: You should give a more explicit description of the process. When $n \ge i$, given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, what is the probability that $X_{n+1} = X_i$?

Comment: What is left unstated is this: What is the mathematical nature of your sample space?  Is it a connected open set of the real numbers?  Of some higher-dimensional euclidean space? Of an infinite-dimensional space? I guess we can infer that it is the first option because you take an infimum of several values. But this should not have to be inferred. (Colors and species are entirely irrelevant to the mathematics.)

Comment: You can assume, as written, that, given a realization from $P \sim \operatorname{DP}(\alpha)$ the samples are i.i.d. realization from $P$, i.e. $X_1,...,X_n | P \sim P$. For further simplicity, you can assume the $X_i$ take values in $R^{+}$. Therefore, the probability of a "new draw", i.e. $X_n \notin \{X_1,...,X_{n-1} \}$, is $\frac{|\alpha|}{|\alpha| + n}$. This is a known property of the predictive distributions of the Dirichlet process.

Comment: So $\Pr(T_1=1)=1.$ The first one has no randomness in it.

Comment: $$T_j:=\inf \left\{n: X_n \notin\left\{X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}\right\}\right\}$$ The index $j$ does not appear to the right of the "equals" sign.

Comment: @MichaelHardy you were right. I took the definition of the arrival time of a new species from this pdf: [here](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~benbr/assets/notes/partitions_rpm_notes.pdf) but it was wrong as you pointed out. Now it should be correct.